# Using Extensions with the Static Class System.Windows.Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, extension-methods

I'm new to C# so bear with me, I'm trying to add methods to the Forms class so that I can show and hide other forms from within a different form if that makes sense. In my extension I have:

```
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static partial class FormExtentsion : Form
    {
        public static void HideForm(this Form frm)
        {
            frm.Hide();
        }

        public static void UnhideForm(this Form frm)
        {
            frm.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

And in my project I have:

```
private void bnTrBack_Click(objects sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Main.UnhideForm();
    this.Close();
}
```

Where Main is my main form. Is there a way to have a form open/close another form? Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: _"Is there a way around this"_ - you haven't told us what 'this' is. BTW your extension method class doesn't need to inherit from `Form` or be partial - `public static class FormExtensions  { public static void HideForm(this Form frm) { frm.Hide(); } …`

Comment: Almost close to what you want https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Extension methods provide a way to seamingly add methods to a class, without changing the class itself. However you still need an instance of that class in order to call them, so I'm afraid extensions don't get you any closer to your goal. You'll need to keep track of instances of your forms somewhere, so you can access them later.

Answer (score 1):

As @CEvenhuis pointed out in a question comment, you need an instance of the main form.

(And, you don't need extension methods at all. Never do—They just allow calling code to look and feel different. But, in this case, in the code you've shown, you are just giving pet names to well-known, existing methods.)

Anyway, in the "child" form, you could have a field to refer to the instance of the main form.

```
Form _parent;
```

And use it like

```
private void bnTrBack_Click(objects sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _parent.Show();
    Close();
}
```

Or, assuming the child is only ever a child of the main form,

```
Main _main;

private void bnTrBack_Click(objects sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _main.Show();
    Close();
}
```

The question would be how to set the field.

It can be set in a constructor:

```
ReadOnly Main _main;
```

And change the designer-generated code from:

```
    public Child()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

to

```
    public Child(Main main)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _main = main;
    }
```

Stepping back a bit, instead of hiding the main form, you could instead—*if appropriate*— show the child form as a [modal dialog](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12045/what-is-a-modal-dialog-window) and receive back a simple result after it closes:

```
var result = new Child().ShowDialog();
```

In general, there are two things to evaluate concerning the options:

1. User experience: Are the controls presented to the users in a way they can understand and in a way that allows them to follow desired workflows?
2. Coupling between classes: Which classes depend on which classes and in what way? Is there a good plan for passing data and control?